# pandas.to_csv() with some words as bold

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe

```
df = [["A1" "B2" "C3"] ["D4" "E5" "F6"]]
```

(All text are strings)
And I want to save it to a file using `df.to_csv()` with the text "E5" coloured / bold. 
Can it be done?

Comment: comma-separated values(csv) files are just collections of values, no styles are associated with them, use another format like excel if you want styling the output

Comment: @gherkin so what is the best way to do that from pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comma-separated values (csv) files do not contain any formatting information, therefore you need to use an Excel format to accomplish what you want. You can do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame([["A1", "B2", "C3"], ["D4", "E5", "F6"]])

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

# Add a header format.
header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for i, row in enumerate(df.values):
    for j, val in enumerate(row):
        if val=='E5': worksheet.write(i, j, val, header_format)
        else: worksheet.write(i, j, val)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

This will output:

[image]